# how can i modify my code to not having this error on python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, weibull

I ve got a trouble on python, i try to get the values from R as it is given on this website https://reliabilityanalyticstoolkit.appspot.com/active_redundancy_integrate_details and get an error

%Run test0.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amine13\Desktop\COURS 3I\math maintenance\test0.py", line 21, in 
x=df_data[:,0]
File "C:\Users\Amine13\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2906, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\Amine13\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

> > > 

Here my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pandas as pd
from math import *
df_data = pd.read_csv('a09.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')

df_data[['duree_de_vie']]

#dat=np.loadtxt (fname=r"C:\Users\Amine13\Desktop\COURS 3I\math maintenance\a09.txt")
x=df_data[:,0]
y=df_data[:,1]
R = lambda y, gamma, eta, beta: (2*exp(-((y-gamma)/eta)**beta)**1*(1-exp(-((y-gamma)/eta)**beta))**1* + 1*exp(-((y-gamma)/eta)**beta)**2*(1-exp(-((y-gamma)/eta)**beta))**0)
```

Any ideas what is causing this error may help me to get through my error.

NB : i replaced t by y (from the website)

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Use `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]` to index into a dataframe or pandas series

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by not calling the column index properly (and not in your last line of code). Here's how you do it in Pandas :

```
x=df_data.iloc[:,0] # Get the first column
y=df_data.iloc[:,1] # Get the second column
```